# How to show latest record per group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person person
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (employee_location employee_location
         INNER JOIN location_status location_status
             ON  employee_location.type = location_status.status_id )
         ON  person.per_id = employee_location.person_id    
ORDER BY person.per_given
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image]

I want to be able to show only the latest record for each person:

[image]

Am I able to do this just by adding something to the MySQL query above?

My schema:

Table = Columns

person = per_id, per_given

employee_location = id, person_id, type, date_time

location_status = status_id, status_type

Comment: is the date_time column part of the person table?

Comment: No, sorry it is part of the employee_location table.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery.  I can speculate on what your tables look like, so I'm guessing the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person p JOIN
     employee_location el
     ON el.person_id = p.per_id JOIN
     location_status ls
     ON  el.type = ls.status_id
WHERE el.date_time = (SELECT MAX(el2.date_time)
                      FROM employee_location el2
                      WHERE el2.per_id = el.per_id
                     )
ORDER BY p.per_given
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html):

```
SELECT per_id, MAX(date_time) FROM person GROUP BY per_id;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it by not excluding my table joins above?

Comment: Of course, but without knowing your schema I cannot give you that answer ;).